# Can't access Angular's data-* attribute

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7 and trying to read the "data-index" attribute of an element I clicked on.

This is the HTML of the element:

```
<div class="carddiv" 
     *ngFor="let card of cardNames; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i" 
     (click)="onCardClick($event)">

  <mat-card> ...
...
</div>
```

..

My code:

```
onCardClick(event : any) : void
{
    let elementId: any = event.target.dataset.index;
    if(elementId)
    {
      console.log(elementId);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("in else");
    }
  }
```

There is more than 1 item so the value received there is not 0, yet It's always outputting the "in else". Why is that?

Comment: Why not pass `i` to `onCardClick` directly (if you need the positional index for some reason)? Also `0` (the index of the 1st element) would evaluate to falsey so if you have only 1 element the index is 0 which  means you enter the `else` block.

Comment: *index* starts from *0* which will always be *false*.

Comment: try to replicate the issue but it's working properly check - https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-attr-data-fetching

Comment: It's actually a learning project of mine to study Angular so it was intentional that I didn't pass I directly

Comment: And about it always being first because of it might be 0 - there is more than 1 element and all of them behave the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're getting `undefined` because the `event.target` points not to your `<div class="carddiv"` element but rather to one of the children.

You can use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead to read `dataset` from the element where you have `data` attribute declared.

```
onCardClick(event : any) : void {
    let elementId: any = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, it's bubbling but `event.target` always points to the thing under the mouse

Comment: That was indeed the case. Another piece of valuable info to learn

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the object and it's index on your click callback function, like this:

```html
<div class="carddiv" 
     *ngFor="let card of cardNames; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i" 
     (click)="onCardClick(card, i)">
...
</div>
```

Your function implementation:

```js
onCardClick(card: any, index: number) : void
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: It's actually a learning project of mine to study Angular so it was intentional that I didn't pass I directly. I want to study how to read the data-* attributes